Condition for a function to change its sign at $x=a$
Consider a situation in which we are only allowed to evaluate the value of a real function $f$ (and its derivatives) at a particular value $a$. Also, assume that the given function is $C^\infty$ smooth.
In this scenario, is it possible to define a necessary and sufficient condition to check whether the output of the function changes in sign while moving infinitesimally over $a$?

My attempt:
Suppose the statement that ‘$f(x)$ changes in sign at $x=a$’ be described as $P(f)$
Then, $$P(f)\equiv\left( f(a)=0\wedge \left(f’(a)\neq0\vee P(f’’)\right)\right)$$
This leads to a recursive condition.

Example
For $f(x)=x^3$ and $a=0$, we get
$$\begin{align}
P(f)&=T\wedge(F\vee P(f’’))\\
&=P(f’’)\\
&=T\wedge(T\vee P(f’’’’))\\
&=T
\end{align}$$
Where $T$ and $F$ stand for booleans $\text{True}$ and $\text{False}$ respectively. Thus, $x^3$ does change sign at $x=0$.

Is my attempt correct? Is there any non-recursive way to build the condition?

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ when $x>0$, and $f(x)=-\exp(-\frac{1}{x^2})$ when $x<0$. You can easily check that all derivatives exist everywhere, and are all $0$ at the origin.
The function changes sign as we pass through $0$.
Its friend $|f|$ likewise has all derivatives $0$ at $0$ but does not change sign.

Did you mean $\exp(-1/x^2)$?

Yours is an apt counter-example to my (wrong) idea. Thank you, and +1. Could it be possible to devise a condition that actually works?

Evaluating the function and its derivatives for both of your $f$ and $|f|$ yield the same value, $0$. So we can’t discriminate on which one changes sign, with the provided information. So there can exist no general condition. Right?

The question is equivalent to the problem of deciding whether the point $a$ is a local extremal point of the function $g(x)=(x-a)f(x).$ If $g^{(n)}(a)=0$ for all $n,$ then we cannot get any information concerning the nature of $a.$ We have  $g^{(n)}(a)=nf^{(n-1)}(a).$ Hence if all the derivatives of $f$ at $a$ vanish we cannot decide whether $f$ changes sign at $a.$

Actually, we are taught at school how to find whether a point is a local extrema of a function using the values of its subsequent derivatives at the point. But as you (and @ancientmathematician) have shown, that is not possible always. Thanks! (+1).

I have suspected that the  result on local extrema is better known. That's why I have reformulated your question so as  to apply that.

Understood, thanks again.
